# Python Tkinter remove previous widgets when updating output

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter but not to Python, and I've been working on taking one of my old codes and putting it in a nice GUI. My current code consists of drop down menus, where after you input your stuff you then press a button which directs to another function which does some calculations and outputs check boxes underneath it.

My issue is when I change those initial choices, the checkbox choices from before stay there, and the new ones just go below it which will mess up the rest of the code later on. I've been messing with frame.grid_forget() at the beginning of the function with the checkboxes but can't get it to work.

I thought that doing something like:

```
def click1(self):
    frame4=Frame(self.window)
    frame4.grid()
    frame4.grid_forget()
    frame4.grid()
```

would work by creating the frame, grid it, remove it, and grid it again so it's effectively resetting itself in that section but it's not working out for me. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't received any responses yet, but for the reference of everyone I played around some more and found an answer:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
  def __init__(self):
    self.window=Tk()
    self.frame=Frame(self.window)
    self.inner=Frame(self.window)
    self.frame.grid()
    self.inner.grid()
    Button(self.frame,text="Click",command=self.clear).grid()
    tkinter.mainloop()
  def click(self):
    self.inner=Frame(self.frame)
    self.inner.grid()
    Label(self.inner,text='Hello!').grid()
  def clear(self):
    self.inner.destroy()
    self.click()



GUI()
```

I was trying to do everything within the function before, but found that the best way was to create the containing frames in the initializing function, and then route the button to destroy them and then recreate them in the function you wanted your button to directly route to. Seems a small detour solved everything, can't believe I spent hours looking for answers and then found it myself. Hopefully someone else can find this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There are control variables available in Tkinter which let you control what appears in widgets based on the content of variables.

```
tk.StringVar (as used below)
tk.DoubleVar can hold a Float
tk.IntVar can hold an int
```

These let you change the content of the widgets without destroying and recreating. Your question refers to CheckBoxes which would be linked to IntVars.

Below is code to show a Label that increments a count each time the button is clicked.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window=Tk()
        self.frame=Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.grid()
        # Define something to change on click.
        self.count=0
        # Create a StringVr to hold it.
        self.label_text=StringVar()
        # Link to a label
        self.label_text.set("Count = "+str(self.count))
        Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.label_text).grid()
        Button(self.frame,text="Click", command=self.on_click).grid()
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def on_click(self):
        # Update Count and the label on click 
        self.count+=1
        self.label_text.set("Count = "+str(self.count))

GUI()
```

Hope this helps